# Best way to search for persons in location

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, search

I have 3 tables that holds the locations, users, with their relevant Ids. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to allow an admin to be able to search for
users in a particular location.

So in short, I'm trying to allow Sam who is the **Admin** to locate users only in his location(restricted to his location), so in this example, Mark who is a regular user is located in `HeadLocation` and `Location1` and can be found by Sam.

**User Table**

```
|---------------------------------|
| UserId   |    Role   | FName    |
|---------------------------------|
|  1       |    Admin  | Sam      |
```

**OfficeUser Table**

```
|---------------------------------------|
| OfficeUserId | OfficeId     | UserId  |
|---------------------------------------|
|  55          |    1         |     1   |
```

**Office Table**

```
|----------------------------------------------|
| OfficeId     | HeadOfficeId |  LocNames      |
|----------------------------------------------|
|  1           |    null      | HeadLocation   |
|----------------------------------------------|
```

**Code**

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SearchUsers(string searchUser, string id)
    {
        //userId from claims
        var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        //gets userId for users with role of admin
        var admin = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Role == "Admin")?.UserId.ToString();


        if (adminExists && admin == userId)
        {
         //This is where I'm unclear...
         var search = from a in _context.OfficeUser
                     join b in _context.Office
                     on a.OfficeId equals a.OfficeId
                          select new
                          {
                            a.UserId,
                            //trying to get names per locations
                          };

        if (search == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUser))
        {
            search = search.Where(a => a.FName.Contains(searchUser));
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound("No Users Found");
        }

        }



        return Ok(search);
    }
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. If the logged in user is admin then what he will search? will search-string can be compared against both User Fname and Location?

Comment: You are correct, I had to re-write my question for extra clarity. So the admin can only locate the users FName and location in the admin's location only.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I will have to test it from my end. I'll be right back

Comment: Use the update answer and if you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: Hi @TanvirArjel, I wasn't able to get the Office.LocNames to work in the Select. 
       var adminLocations = _context.OfficeUser.Where(ou => ou.UserId == userId).Select(ou => ou.Office.LocNames).ToList(); Do I need to join OfficeUser with Office tables?

Comment: Don't you have `Office` Navigation property in your `OfficeUser` class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188643/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-chris-h).

Comment: add `public Office Office {get; set; }` to your `OfficeUser` class.

Comment: Yes you are very right. There is a navigation property. I noticed that you used ou.Office.LocNames in this line of code =>        var searchQuery = _context.OfficeUsers.Where(ou => adminLocations.Contains(ou.Office.LocNames)).Select(ou => ou.User);
I wasn't able to access ou.OfficeLocNames within the Contains.

Comment: Now is it okay?

Comment: Thank you very much Tanvir. I will do further testing from my end, but I believe it will work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the generalized view of your query. There can some typing mistakes as I have typed this in here, not in visual studio editor.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchUsers(string searchUser, string id)
{
    var loggedInUserId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    var isLoggedInUserAdmin = _context.User.Any(u => u.UserId == loggedInUserId && u.Role == "Admin");

    if (isLoggedInUserAdmin)
    {
       var adminLocations = _context.OfficeUser.Where(ou => ou.UserId == userId).Select(ou => ou.Office.LocNames).ToList();

       var searchQuery = _context.OfficeUsers.Where(ou => adminLocations.Contains(ou.Office.LocNames)).Select(ou => ou.User);

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUser))
       {
            searchQuery = searchQuery.Where(q => q.FName.Contains(searchUser));
       }

       var adminLocUserList  = searchQuery.ToList();
       return Ok(userList)
    }

    var userList = _context.OfficeUsers.Where(ou.User.FName.Contains(searchUser)).Select(ou => ou.User).ToList();

    return Ok(userList);
}
```